# Importing a Typescript interface vs using a namespace

Tags: typescript, syntax

I'm using Typescript and AngularJs (1.6). When I need to declare a variable with an angular's type, I often hesitating between the two following syntaxes:

```js
constructor(private $sce: ng.ISCEService) {}
```

and

```js
import { ISCEService } from 'angular';

constructor(private $sce: ISCEService) {}
```

I assume these two pieces of code are doing the exact same things, but I'm not 200% sure.

My favourite is the first one as it does not require an import, but maybe I'm missing something. I'm curious, do you have some advise / opinion / best practice?

Answer (score 1):

> I assume these two pieces of code are doing the exact same things, but I'm not 200% sure.

They are saying the same thing. Difference depends on how [your project is setup](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/project/modules.html)

- If you are using angular globally e.g. using a script tag then use `ng.`
- If you are using modules e.g. with webpack use imports `import { ISCEService } from 'angular';`

Comment: Thank you basarat. Interesting. Does it mean that if I plan to use webpack in the future, the import syntax is the way to go? Even with the help of angular typings?

Comment: You should use webpack today to keep sanity 